# Python argparse @fromfile argument not recognised

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to set an argument in a "fromfile" text file, but it's not recognised, however if I copy/paste the SAME arguments into the command line, it works! What's going on?

Here's a minimal example:

A `main.py` like this:

```
def main(args):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
    parser.add_argument("--load-model", default=None, help="model to load")
    main(parser.parse_args())
```

And text file `args.txt`:

```
--load-model foo
```

Called like this:

```
> python main.py @args.txt
usage: main.py [--load-model LOAD_MODEL]
main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --load-model foo
```

But the "unrecognised argument" is identical to the argument listed above ??

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the "fromfile" text file needs to be ***delimited by newlines***.

If my argument file is like this:

```
--load-model
foo
```

it works!